# HTML Input Field to Javascript Function to Console

Tags: javascript, html, scope, event-handling

I'm trying to echo the input from the input field to the console but can't print the input outside the HTML field, here an example :

```js
function getInput(input) {
 var input = document.getElementById("EchoInput").value;
  console.log(input);
}

//These are the "external" inputs I'd like to print in the console.
getInput("test");
getInput("one");
getInput("two");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="EchoInput" onblur="getInput()">
```

As you can see it does work using `document.getElementById("EchoInput").value;` but when testing the function with "test", "one" and "two" inputs it doesn't work.

I'm super newb with code but believe there's a problem of variable scope here and that `getElementById().value;` is taking over the bottom three functions.

The other alternative to print the bottom functions is by removing the event handler, but makes the input for the field `undefined` which defeats the purpose.

Is there a way to accept both inputs ?

Thanks a lot for your help, I've looked for answers here and found solutions using JQuery or similar advanced ones I didn't understand, apologies if it's a recurring issue.

Cheers.

K.

Comment: Have a look to `$( document ).ready(function() { });`

Comment: @HappyCoding jQuery is not the solution

Comment: there is no need jquery here

Comment: @Robiseb, have a look to the correct answer. jQuery is the solution ;)

Comment: @HappyCoding, where did you see some jQuery ?

Comment: @Robiseb read the article dude https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @HappyCoding I know that ^^, but there is no jQuery in the correct answer. It's just a [self invoking function](https://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of "self invoking function" to call the `getInput` and more over you would not need `document.GetElementById` statement.

Just use `onblur="getInput(this.value)"`

```
<input type="text" id="EchoInput" onblur="getInput(this.value)">
```

**Javascript**

```
function getInput(input) {
  console.log(input);
}

(function() {
  //These are the "external" inputs I'd like to print in the console.
  getInput("test");
  getInput("one");
  getInput("two");
})();
```

```js
function getInput(input) {
  console.log(input);
}
  
(function() {
  //These are the "external" inputs I'd like to print in the console.
  getInput("test");
  getInput("one");
  getInput("two");
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="EchoInput" onblur="getInput(this.value)">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nikhil, it's definitely what I was looking for, I worried it would take more code to fix this issue ;)
Robiseb & ArturN > Thank you guys too, it's great to see other version of the solution, I can see how to use them in a different context.

Comment: Glad it helped .. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your input value is empty when your page is loaded.
Test with a default value and you'll see your three function calls log the value.

In the `getInput` function, set as argument the input ID (*string*). If the element exists, the function will return the value.

```js
function getInput(elementId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var input = element ? element.value : '';
  console.log(input);
}

//These are the "external" inputs I'd like to print in the console.
getInput("EchoInput");
getInput("");
getInput("test");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="EchoInput" onblur="getInput(this.id)" value="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this:

```
function getInput(input) {
  var value = input || document.getElementById("EchoInput").value;
  console.log(value);
}
```

If the input is undefined (the event call), you'll get the value from the field. If the input is given (pure function call), the value given will be printed.